# How can I define multiple class objects with a for loop in python?

Tags: python, oop, multidimensional-array, pygame, tile

So I am making a basic tile based game with pygame. I need to render a 20x20 grid of ground tiles on the screen. I want every tile to be an object of a class because the player will be able to change the environment.

I need to store the tile objects in a 2D array. My problem is defining all the objects using a for loop, each of the objects having a different name and properties.

Is this even possible to do or is there a better way of rendering tiles in pygame?

This is the class, there is no point is showing other tile rendering code since it doesn't even remotely work:

```
visGround = [[]]

class groundTile(object):
    def __init__(self, tileType, act_x, act_y, game_x, game_y):
        self.tileType = tileType
        self.act_x = act_x
        self.act_y = act_y
        self.game_x = game_x
        self.game_y = game_y
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *each of the objects having a different name and properties*. You can do a nested `for` loop iterating along the x and y axes, but I need more details to properly help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need,

```
gridHeight = 20
gridWidth = 20

visGround = []


class groundTile(object):
    def __init__(self, tileType, act_x, act_y, game_x, game_y):
        self.tileType = tileType
        self.act_x = act_x
        self.act_y = act_y
        self.game_x = game_x
        self.game_y = game_y


for i in range(gridHeight):
    visGround.append([])
    for j in range(gridWidth):
        visGround[i].append(groundTile('Title Type', 'Act X', 'Act Y', j, i))

print(visGround)
```

You can adjust the size of the grid at the top and it will change the size of the 2 arrays. I have placed i and j in the game x and y on the assumption that these represent the location on the grid.